# Does this file exist or not?

Tags: files

I'm troubleshooting my [RPi-Monitor](http://rpi-experiences.blogspot.com/p/rpi-monitor.html) installation and bumped into this seemingly insane situation:

[image]

Somehow the file `opcn2_pm1.rdd` exists enough to be seen when `ls -l` is called on its parent directory, but not enough for `ls` (or any other application) to see it.

What's going on here? Does this file exist?

---

*Sure, I'm working on a Pi but this question isn't Pi-specific AFAICT so I'm asking here instead of there. A more descriptive question title is welcome :)*

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy/paste the terminal output into a code block in your question instead.

Comment: `ocpn2_pm1.rdd` != `opcn2_pm1.rdd`. Take a sleep!

Comment: Wish I'd seen this comment 10 minutes ago! Thanks Ipor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ran:

```
rrdtool last opcn2_pm1.rdd
```

However, that's not the name of the file.  The name of the file actually is:

```
ocpn2_pm1.rdd
```

As correctly shown by `ls`.

Comment: You're right there is a typo... but please examine all the output: the file in question does not appear in the results of `| grep opc`

Comment: @patricktokeeffe Sure not. By your `ls` the file is named `ocp` , not `opc` that you grep. There is not any typo error in your question. Your  screenshot advises that file name starts with `ocp`

Comment: How disappointing.. I've been typing and retyping and starting over and never found that transpose. Thanks @george-vasiliou

Comment: @patricktokeeffe You are welcome... but don't thank me :-) Has already been spotted by other fellow "linuxers"...

Comment: Indeed, jayhendren figured it out first so he gets the prize. :)